# Murder of crows silent assassin rating

Tags: hitman-blood-money

In the murder of crows I knocked out Raymund and Angelina and threw them of the railing, but got a professional rating, I tried dropping  the piano on Angelina and also got the professional rating, so does anyone know how to achieve silent assassin rating?

Comment: What difficulty are you playing on?

Comment: I played like i explained on rookie

Comment: Are you injuring anyone else? Are you being caught?

Comment: At the end of the mission it will give you your play through stats. What does it say under Total Kills, Accidents, Bodies Found, Covers Blown, Witnesses and Caught On Camera?

Noise and Violence might help, but I don't think that would make a difference with what your doing.

Comment: I just knocked out two people but i have done it in other missions and acheived silent assassin  , and everything is 0 on the stats screen except the accident which is 3 meaning all kills where accident and there is no witnesses so i dont understand

Comment: I would recommend trying the level again without knocking anybody out. If you have to knock somebody out, kill them. Make it look like an accident. Accidents should 100% allow for a Silent Assassin rank, but I question whether knocking people out effects the rank.

Comment: Well i did another mission by knocking out 2 people and still got the silent assassin :|

Answer (score 1):

A Silent Assassin rating is earned by completing the following objectives:

- No bodies found, unless the death is made to look accidental.
- No witnesses.
- Cover kept intact throughout the entire level.
- Any captured footage collected (surveillance tapes).

Furthermore, on *Expert* and *Professional* difficulty:

- Left level with suit.
- Left level with all custom weapons (weapons brought into the level).
- Left level with the diamond case

[Here is a link to the IGN guide](http://au.ign.com/faqs/2008/hitman-trilogy-silent-assassion-walkthrough-892563), where the writer achieved Silent Assassin in 17 minutes on professional. The methods for killing the targets appear identical to yours.

I am going to assume it is the diamond case you are missing. The guide details picking it up at the start, and stashing it for collection at the end.

> From your starting stand still. You'll notice a man dressed in a red bird suit
>   will enter the restaurant and walk over to the bar. He will talk with a
>   civilian before leaving. He has the diamond case. Now the case is important
>   for two reasons. One, you need to retrieve that case to get an SA rating as
>   mentioned above and two, if that case reaches Mark Purayah then Kulinsky will
>   make his move on the politician. In other words if that case does NOT reach
>   Purayah then you will have no time limit what so ever on this mission.
>
> Now when the red bird leaves the restaurant he will either head left or right.
>   If he heads right just restart the mission as it's much easier if he heads
>   left. Follow him making sure to stay on the opposite side of the road from
>   him. After a little while he will head down a narrow alleyway and into an open
>   square. Quickly sedate him as soon as he enters the square. Drag his body
>   through the door on your right and hide his body in here. Take his suit and
>   head back out to the square. Pick up the case and place it in the room where
>   you dumped the red birds' body. You'll pick it up later on.

When it is time to escape;

> With Kulinsky taken care of make your way back to the central square with four
>   paths leading into it (where you sedated the red bird). Once you arrive there
>   head into the small room where your suit is and change back into it. Then pick
>   up the diamond case and head out the room. Take the southern path out of the
>   square, walk over to the small metal barriers and escape.

Comment: Well no i had the diamond case when i escaped

Comment: If you were playing on rookie, that would not have made a difference regardless. You will have to check your end of level statistics. If you could screenshot it and provide it with your question, that would make it a lot easier to pinpoint where your hiccup is.

Comment: Ok but as i commented on my question there is 3 accidents and every thing else is 0 ,  i will capture even its video if i could upload it but unfortunately my internet speed has dropped drasticaly this week

Comment: Yeah, I had a couple of cases where I would not get the rating I had expected, with a "perfect" level score. I had put it down to knocking out people, or otherwise triggering some sort of alarm (actual alarm, blown cover, witnesses etc.) with out it going over to the final score sheet.

I believe the problem there is in the score sheet representing the level play through 100% as this only happened when I was a tiny bit sloppy.

Not much you can do on that account, other then use the sheet as a guide, but not an absolute indication.